# weird behaviour of QTimer

Tags: python, pyqt, qtimer

I have the following function where I am using `QTimer` to update my `counter` after every `1` second:

```
def somefunc(): 
  if self.pushButton_13.text() == 'OFF':
            self.pushButton_13.setText('ON')
            timer1.setInterval(1000) #timer1 is global variable
            timer1.timeout.connect(lambda: self.counter(15))
            timer1.start()
  else:
            self.pushButton_13.setText('OFF')
            timer1.stop()
            print timer1.timerId()

def counter(self, var):
    if var == 15:
        count = int(str(self.lineEdit_15.text()))

        count = count + 1
        print count
        self.lineEdit_15.setText(QtCore.QString(str(count)))
```

When I first press button `counter` is working properly but if click button again to stop timer and then again restart, the counter value updates by `2` for every `1` second - instead it should be updated by `1`. Similarly if I again click the button to stop the counter and again restart then counter updates by `3` and so on. Where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you press the button you make a new connection, that is independent to the previous ones. This causes that the `counter` slot is called multiple number of times, once for each connection. From Qt's [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#connect-3):

> Every connection you make emits a signal, so duplicate connections emit two signals. You can break a connection using disconnect().

You should set up (i.e. create it and connect `timeout` to appropriate slots) the timer only once, and then only `start` and `stop` it as many times as you need.

Alternatively, the simplest solution for your code is this:

```
        #...
        timer1.setInterval(1000)  
        timer1.disconnect()       # removes previous connections
        timer1.timeout.connect(lambda: self.counter(15))
        timer1.start()
        #...
```